# Unexpected behaviour in Ipython console

Tags: python, ipython, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run a code both from Ipython console and cmd.

Here is the code, But importantly please check the 2 scenarios I described below

```
#coding: utf-8

import sys, logging, time, os, random
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool, \
    cpu_count, current_process, Manager

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

def producer_task(q, fibo_dict):
    for i in range(15):
        value = random.randint(1, 20)
        fibo_dict[value] = None
        logger.info("Producer [%s] putting value [%d] into queue.. " % (current_process().name, value))
        q.put(value)

def consumer_task(q, fibo_dict):
    while not q.empty():
        value = q.get(True, 0.05)
        a, b = 0, 1
        for item in range(value):
            a, b = b, a + b
            fibo_dict[value] = a
        logger.info("consumer [%s] getting value [%d] from queue..." % (current_process().name, value))

data_queue = Queue()
number_of_cpus = cpu_count()
manager = Manager()
fibo_dict = manager.dict()

producer = Process(target=producer_task, args=(data_queue, fibo_dict))
producer.start()
producer.join()
```

2 Scenarios:

1) When I save the code as tes*.py and run from CMD (python test.py) it works correctly,
2) WHen I copy the code as is in Ipython and execute (Ctrl + Enter). I am getting this strange error AttributeError: 'module' objet has no attribute 'consumer_task'

Could someone explain where is the error. Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you copying this into `ipython`?  via the clipboard copy-n-paste? `%paste`, `import`, `%run`.   My first choice would be the `%run` magic.

Comment: I am using ctrl+c, ctrl+v windows shortcut, this works in every other case, since I have been programming in python, just that this has been a deadlock

Comment: Multiprocessing doesn't work very well in interactive contexts, especially on Windows. See the note in this section of the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers